# Finding difference of 2 n-dimensional vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensors, cross-product, dimensional-analysis

I have been meaning to find the difference between $2$ $n$-dimensional vectors. I am looking for a convex function (anti-commutative) that finds a signed difference between the two vectors (in the range $-1$ to $1$).

Taking $L_2$ norm certainly provides the distance between the two but with a strictly positive range.

Cross product seems like a possible direction but cross product of two $n$-dimensional vectors results in a tensor of rank $n-2$ whose sign is computed by noting the permutation of the indices of the tensor. However, I could not find any details in this direction.

Can anyone help in determining a function with a simpler computation of a signed difference of $2$ $n$-dimensional vectors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly what do you want this function to do? (For example, defining $f(u,v)=0$ for all $u$, $v$ presumably doesn't do what you want, but it's not ruled out by anything you said...)

Comment: If a and b are two positive univariate variables, then a function f(a,b)=a-b calculates the difference between a and b and also f(a,b)=-f(b,a). The range of this function includes both positive and negative values.
I want to calculate such signed difference if a and b are two multivariate vectors which f(a,b)=0 does not suffice. In essence, I want to calculate not just the distance between 2 vectors but also the direction.